# How can I see the transfer speed when transferring files with Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer, data-monitoring

I transfer files with  Bluetooth between a Google Pixel 6 and a Samsung Galaxy A8+. How can I see the transfer speed when transferring files with  Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: You can not see speed when transferring files via bluetooth.

Long Answer:
Android OS by default does not have an interface for Bluetooth transfer speed or show it during the data transfer. In most cases only transfer progress will be available.

Bluetooth Broadcast Receiver only exposes RSSI or link quality and you need to do your own calculation of speed for each RSSI range.